# Is there a Haskell library for dates?

Tags: date, haskell

Is there a function in Haskell that will allow me to enter component of a date (like a string representation or day month year components) that I can get information from (like day of week, days in a month, etc.)?

I've looked online and it looks like there are a lot of custom libraries, but I'm hoping there's one in the standard prelude library of ghci 10.6.4 that's just not well documented?

Comment: I still can't find a function: **`dayOfWeek :: SomeDateType -> WeekDayType`**.

Comment: Example: `dayOfWeek (fromGregorian 2014 7 15) {- evals to Tuesday -}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are [Data.Time.Calendar](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/libraries/time/Data-Time-Calendar.html) and [Data.Time.Format](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/libraries/time/Data-Time-Format.html) in the [time library](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.4/html/libraries/time/index.html) sufficient?

You can parse a string representation of a date and get the length of a month using `gregorianMonthLength`.  Not sure about day of the week, though you could format the date as a string using a format that just displays the week day.

Comment: I'd seen the Calendar, but I think I'd not looked into the format which seems to have most of the information that I'd need :)  Thanks!

Comment: (...noob obviously new to haskell): I'm using GHC. I can't find the module for time anywhere on my machine. googling for it doesn't give me any hits for a place where it lives. I'm confused. Is that part of standard GHCI dist & if so where the heck would that module be, if not, where can I get the module? thx

Comment: Best I found, but the library could use some improvements. See my comments on the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search turns up [this](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~bringert/darcs/parsedate/doc/), which may be what you want. It lets you parse strings representing dates and extract information from them.

Comment: I was hoping for something in the standard library so I wouldn't have to insure the end user would have spesific external libraries :)

Comment: What kind of end user do you have? a Haskell library isn't something like python/perl/ruby very late binding soo if you compile your code you should a one solid a.out

Answer (score 1):

You can find the day of the week with `mondayStartWeek` or `sundayStartWeek`, depending on whether you think a week starts on Monday, or on Sunday. Both functions are in `Data.Time.Calendar.OrdinalDate`.

```
λ> snd $ mondayStartWeek $ fromGregorian 2017 10 3
2
```

In the above example, the return value is `2`, which indicates the second day of the week. Since the function is called `mondayStartWeek`, Monday is the first day, so `2` corresponds to Tuesday. This is true of October 3, 2017.

## A warning regarding week numbers

Both functions return a tuple, where the second element is the week day. As far as I can tell, that should be trustworthy.

The first element, however, is the week number of the year. Be careful with that, because the rules for week numbering are political. If I remember correctly, in USA, week 1 is the week that contains January 1. That's not the case in Denmark, where I live. Here, week 1 is the first week where Thursday falls in the new year. This can mean that December 31 can fall in week 1 of the next year. IIRC, this is the rule for many other European countries. Some years, the American and the European week numbers align, but some years, they don't.