# How to get date in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm working with Haskell and I would like to get the year of the current date in haskell. I want the output to be an Int or String. 
Thanks.

Comment: this question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035742/is-there-a-haskell-function-for-dates

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot have a function `getDate :: () -> Int` that will actually get you the date. I assume you mean you want something like `currentDate :: IO date`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From https://wiki.haskell.org/Getting_the_current_date:

```
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar

date :: IO (Integer, Int, Int) -- :: (year, month, day)
date = getCurrentTime >>= return . toGregorian . utctDay
```

If you only want the year…

```
year :: IO Integer
year = (\(y, _, _) -> y) <$> date
```

Comment: How can I get it without being IO Integer?

Comment: @Cthulhu – you cannot. That's kind of the whole point. Reading the time is not a pure function, it's a "step" which would have to occur at a particular point in time during the execution of your program. That's not how Haskell works – you have no idea if, when, or how many times any given function in Haskell will run. If your Haskell program needs to express computations dealing with impure values, you do so in an `IO` action which represents an imperative program.

There is technically an escape hatch, but it's for advanced use cases, and I am not even going to say what it is here.